# How to convert "1-D int array" to "int" in Julia (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: arrays, int, julia

There is a similar question in C [How to convert int array to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564800/how-to-convert-int-array-to-int); however, I cannot find such question in Julia.

My question is the following:

There is an error about `v[1] = x'*y`
[image]

So I try to find the reason and it show that:
[image]

However, `x^Ty=2` so if you directly type `2`, it is `Int64` and there is no error as shown in the following:

[image]

So how to transfrom Array{Int64,1} to Int 64,1?

Comment: `arr_to_int{T<:Number}(x::Vector{T}) = length(x) == 1 ? Int(x[1]) : error("Input array does not have one element")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the corresponding convert method:

```
Base.convert{T}(Float64, x::Array{T, 1}) = float(x[1])
```

Or in general

```
Base.convert{T,K}(::Type{K}, x::Array{T, 1}) = Base.convert(K, x[1])
```

Example:

```
v = zeros(Complex{Float64}, 3)
x = [1, 1]
y = [1, 1]
v1 = x'*y
v[1] = v1
v[2] = 45
v[3] = 100
v
```

Result:

```
3-element Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
   2.0+0.0im
  45.0+0.0im
 100.0+0.0im
```

Comment: Even though this is marked with a checkmark, the correct answer is in fact @Gnimuc 's below. The approach here can cause all kinds of problems, by replacing any Vector with its first element when passed to a function that expects a scalar.

Answer (score 5):

The reason under the hood is that Julia-0.5 still doesn't [take vector transposes seriously](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4774), actually, `x'` is a 1x2 matrix:

```
julia> x'
1×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1
```

Apparently, you would like to get the dot product of `x` and `y`, but technically speaking `x'*y` is not the right syntax, you should use `dot(x,y)` or `\cdot[tab]`:

```
julia> x ⋅ y
2
```

This issue has already been fixed on Julia-0.6 master by introducing a new type `RowVector`:

```
julia> x'
1×2 RowVector{Int64,Array{Int64,1}}:
 1  1

julia> x'*y
2
```