# Generate secure random number with SecureRandom

Tags: java, secure-random

How can I generate a **6** digit integer using `SecureRandom` class of Java?

I am trying the following code to generate random numbers :

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
int secureNumber = secureRandom.nextInt();
```

It is generating random numbers with any length including negative number. I don't find any method in `SecureRandom` class to provide a range of numbers. I want to generate a **6** digits *positive* random number

Comment: SO is not the source code implementation resource. Come here with your code attempts which have some particular problem

Comment: So you are needing a number that is padded with leading zeros so that it is 6 digits long, correct?

Comment: No. I could be any 6 digit number.

Comment: `int secureNumber = secureRandom.nextInt(900000) + 100000;`

Comment: @shmosel what about the six digit number 023487? You can't generate any number w/any leading zeros w/your solution...

Comment: @rabbitguy 023487 is not a 6 digit integer.

Comment: @shmosel That's why he says number and not just integer. 023487 is a 6 digit number although it is not a 6 digit integer.

Comment: @DavyM I'll bet you a 6 digit figure it's neither of those.

Comment: @shmosel The person who assigned James Bond's agent number would disagree

Answer (score 3):

Maybe using this code?

```
String.format("%06d", secureRandom.nextInt(999999));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

simply done it with an array

```
int[] arr = new int[6];
Random rand = new SecureRandom();
for(int i= 0; i< 6 ; i++){
    // 0 to 9
    arr[i] = rand.nextInt(10);   
}
```

Dont know if you need it in another type (if you want int look here: [How to convert int array to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564800/how-to-convert-int-array-to-int)

Comment: You know you linked it to a question dealing w/C#, right? It's similar, but not exact on how you'd do it in Java

Comment: Technically it works the same, but yeah its another language even tho the syntax is basically the same

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
static String generate(int len){
   SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
   String result = (sr.nextInt(9)+1) +"";
   for(int i=0; i<len-2; i++) result += sr.nextInt(10);
   result += (sr.nextInt(9)+1);
   return result;
}
```

**Test:**

```
public static void main(String[] argv){
   for(int i=3; i<25; i++) System.out.println(generate(i));
}
```

**Output:**

```
639
1617
84489
440757
9982141
28220183
734679206
1501896787
29547455245
417101844095
9997440470982
24273208689568
235051176494856
9515304245005008
73519153118911442
665598930463570609
9030671114119582966
96572353350467673335
450430466373510518561
9664395407658562145827
26651025927755496179441
421157180102739403860678
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create a string of **6** random digits.

```
SecureRandom test = new SecureRandom();
int result = test.nextInt(1000000);
String resultStr = result + "";
if (resultStr.length() != 6) 
    for (int x = resultStr.length(); x < 6; x++) resultStr = "0" + resultStr;
System.out.println(resultStr); // prints the 6 digit number
```

Should work quite nicely. Tested so that it would spit out **1000** numbers and all of them were **6** digits long including leading zeros for when the random number initially chosen was less than **100,000**.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(values);
int number = Math.abs(ByteBuffer.wrap(values).getInt());
while (number >= 1000000) {
     number /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it using Java IntStream

```
private final SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();

public String generateCode() {
    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> secureRandom.nextInt(10))
            .limit(6)
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append).toString();
}
```